# Groovy: how to use Exceptions or <If> <else> construction with MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, exception, groovy, if-statement

I have a query from table of MySQL database, and i want check: have i got this number in table and if not - println that this number not in database, if this number exist - println that this number exist. How i can do that, using Exceptions or (If) (else) construction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using an in memory hsql db:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB',      // JDBC Url
                           'sa',                          // Username
                           '',                            // Password
                           'org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver')  // Driver classname

def tim = 'tim'

def name = sql.firstRow( "SELECT name FROM users WHERE userid=$tim" )?.name

if( name ) {
  println "Name was $name"
}
else {
  println "Name not found"
}
```